# Can't retrieve values from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array as follows along with a reshape:

```
X = M.dot(X1) + B #prints [[value1 value2 ]]
X.reshape(2,1)
```

I am then trying to plot this point along with others as follows:

```
plt.plot([X[0],...],[X[1],...],'-og','LineWidth',2)
```

However, I can't retrieve any values and I get index 1 out of range. How can I get rid of this problem and access the two values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: `.reshape` does not work in place but instead returns something. Your Original `X` has shape `(1 ,2)`. In your plot statement `X[1]` does access the row with index 1 (i.e. the "second" row) – which does not exist.

Anyway, try

```
X = X.squeeze()  # X.shape now is (2,)
```

This converts `X` to an 1d array. Then `X[1]` accesses the second element.

Alternatively, you could change your plot statement to use `X[0, 1]` instead of `X[1]` for your original `X` with 1 row and two columns.